# SonarQube warning "Insufficient branch coverage by unit tests"

Tags: java, sonarqube

Does anybody knows about this issue “Insufficient branch coverage by unit tests”? My class code coverage is 99% but I am keep getting sonar warning for that same class “Insufficient branch coverage by unit tests : 111 more branches need to be covered by unit tests to reach the minimum threshold of 65.0% branch coverage.”
Normally this error occurred due to Insufficient coverage of if/else condition as we have to handle positive/negative both scenarios.  Does anybody knows anything else about this warning?

Thanks
Sach

Answer (score 6):

This means that you have branches in your code that are not covered.

For instance :

```
boolean foo() {
  return a || b || c; 
}
```

if in your tests you always have a that is true, then you are covering the line indeed but not all the branches possible.

Please also watch out for try with resources as this generates a lot of branches in bytecode (and you don't see them in source) and you are most probably not covering all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good Wikipedia page explaining the differences between the different coverage metrics:
[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage#Basic_coverage_criteria)

**Branch coverage in short covers if-else situations**, where you are expected to test BOTH cases to achieve 100% coverage.

Comment: I am using eclemma to find out code coverage and it shows branch coverage is not 100%. like if you have if condition and if both condition(positive/negative) is not satisfied then it says "1 of 2 branches are not covered". In my class I can see all branches are covered related to if/else and try/catch but still I am getting issue.